# Where is /proc/sys/vm/flush_mmap_pages gone?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, redhat

I found the Linux start to support kernel parameter `/proc/sys/vm/flush_mmap_pages` at [redhat 5.2 release note](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/5/html/5.2_release_notes/sect-red_hat_enterprise_linux-release_notes-kernel_related_updates). It allows kernel don't sync the mmaped dirty pages to memory, it avoids kernel flush inconsistency pages to disk.

But I couldn't find this parameter in any OS I can access, including the "oldest" RedHat 6:

```
[louchenyao@instance-1 vm]$ uname -a
Linux instance-1 2.6.32-754.11.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jan 22 17:25:23 EST 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[louchenyao@instance-1 vm]$ pwd
/proc/sys/vm
[louchenyao@instance-1 vm]$ ls | grep flush_mmap_page
[louchenyao@instance-1 vm]$
```

I have no idea where this parameter is gone. May I need any extra setting?

Could you give any suggestion about how to find the history discussion of this parameter?

Answer (score 0):

After the investigation, this parameter only existed in RedHat/CentOS 5. At first, the clients of RedHat complained the writeback strike the performance, RedHat [fixed this](http://sophie.aero.jussieu.fr/distrib/Scientific%20Linux/5x/x86_64/by-pkgid/27922b4260f65d317aabda37e42bbbff/files/2167) by introducing `flush_mmap_pages` parameter.

This parameter was never merged into the mainstream kernel. I speculate they can workaround this problem by [tunning other parameters](http://jmoiron.net/blog/mmap2/).